# I need to expand and collapse a table row

Tags: jquery, expandable, collapsable

I got the following code from an answer already on this site. With the following JQuery code the table rows are collapsed by default and then by clicking on the 'heading id' I can expand the table. However, if I click on the heading id again the rows will not collapse. I need to add something to this code to make it do that. If possible I would also like to add a +  and a - icon that the user can click on instead of the heading id itself. Can anyone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <title>Master Vocab List</title>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">  
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#collapse").hide();
                    $("#collapse1").hide();
                    $("#collapse2").hide();
                    $("#collapse3").hide();
                    $("#collapse4").hide();
                    $("#collapse5").hide();
                    $("#collapse6").hide();
                    $("#collapse7").hide();
                    $("#collapse8").hide();

                });


                $("#heading").click(function(){                 
                    $("#collapse").show();
                    $("#collapse1").show();
                    $("#collapse2").show();
                    $("#collapse3").show();
                    $("#collapse4").show();
                    $("#collapse5").show();
                    $("#collapse6").show();
                    $("#collapse7").show();
                    $("#collapse8").show();



                });
            </script>
```

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="heading"  colspan = "2"><b>Connectors and  
            Transitions</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="collapse">
            <td>primero</td>
            <td>first</td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="collapse1">
           <td>después</td>
           <td>afterwards</td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="collapse2">
           <td>pero</td>
           <td>but</td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="collapse3">
           <td>y</td>
           <td>and</td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="collapse4">
           <td>luego</td>
           <td>afterwards</td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="collapse5">
           <td>antes</td>
           <td>beforehand</td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="collapse6">
           <td>finalmente</td>
           <td>finally</td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="collapse7">
           <td>por ejemplo</td>
           <td>for example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="collapse8">
           <td>mientras</td>
           <td>while</td>
      </tr>
  </table>`
```

Comment: You can just add and image or font awesome icon and move the Id property from the heading to this new element to accomplish the +. Then instead of calling .show do .toggle in your code

Comment: Thank you for the information. Works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what you ultimate goal is, so I will answer your question using the example you have (which is a table with two columns, where the first row is styled as a heading).

It's tedious to add an id to each and every row.  You'll get more bang for your buck using `DOM` traversal.  So, in your case, you can do:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //find all rows after the first row and hide them
  $('table').find('tr:gt(0)').hide();
  //add a class to track expanded / collapsed (for CSS styling)
  $('#heading').addClass('hCollapsed');


  $("#heading").click(function() {
    //#heading is a cell, so go up to the parent, which is the first tr.  Toggle the hide/show status of those rows.
    $(this).parent().siblings().toggle();
    //then adjust the classes accordingly (for CSS styling)
    if ($(this).hasClass('hCollapsed')) {
      $(this).removeClass('hCollapsed').addClass('hExpanded');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('hExpanded').addClass('hCollapsed');
    }

  });
});
```

And then, as a simple solution, you can use CSS to add a + or -.

**CSS**

```
.hCollapsed::before {
  content: "+ ";
}

.hExpanded::before {
  content: "- ";
}

#heading {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Fiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/cwtd2g18/

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much! I basically just have a long list of vocabulary words grouped under different headings so I will be applying this code to multiple headings and have them all collapsable for a cleaner presentation. Thanks again.