# HTML Page - Expanding Data

Tags: html

I want to display some information on a webpage that will allow a user to drill down into the numbers if they want. I know what I want it to do, but not sure where to even look to start figuring it out.

What I'd like to do is the following (or something like it)

```
     Date     Item     Total
   + 7/2/2018 Apples   1000
```

When the + (or whatever, even the row) is clicked it expands into the following

```
   Date      Item              Total
 - 7/2/2018  Apples            1000
   7/2/2018  Honey Crisp       250
   7/2/2018  Golden Delicious  500
   7/2/2018  Granny Smith      250
```

Is something like this possible? Where do I start looking?

Comment: Yes it is possible using Javascript. Please share what you have already tried, and explain why it isn't working. Stack Overflow is not a free drive-thru code generation service; no-one is going to write it for you.

Comment: I don't have any code and not asking for code. What I'm asking for is the theory to research.  If you notice in the original post I specifically state I'm asking for where to start my search. Thanks.

Comment: In which case my comment mentioning Javascript should be sufficient to start your research.

Comment: Look into drop-down lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to expand and collapse a table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933640/i-need-to-expand-and-collapse-a-table-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure CSS Solution :

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

label {
  background-color: #AAAFAB;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  color: white;
}

li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]~ul {
  max-height: 0;
  max-width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~ul {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label:before {
  transform-origin: 25% 50%;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-width: 8px 12px;
  border-left-color: white;
  margin-left: -20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  content: '';
  color: #AAAFAB;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" /><label for="cb1">Level 1</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" /><label for="cb2">Level 2-A</label>
        <ul>
          <li><label>Level 3-A</label> Content</li>
          <li><label>Level 3-B</label> Content</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" /><label for="cb3">Level 2-B</label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb5" /><label for="cb5">Level 3-A</label>
            <ul>
              <li><label>Level 4-A</label> Content</li>
              <li><label>Level 4-B</label> Content</li>
              <li><label>Level 4-C</label> Content</li>
              <li><label>Level 4-D</label> Content</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb6" /><label for="cb6">Level 3-B</label>
            <ul>
              <li><label>Level 4-A</label> Content</li>
              <li><label>Level 4-B</label> Content</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb7" /><label for="cb7">Level 3-C</label>
            <ul>
              <li><label>Level 4-A</label> Content</li>
              <li><label>Level 4-B</label> Content</li>
              <li><label>Level 4-C</label> Content</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" /><label for="cb4">Level 2-C</label>
        <ul>
          <li><label>Level 3-A</label> Content</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: MajiD, James.. Thanks.. I seriously wasn't looking for code just topic to research on how to accomplish my task. I appreciate the help.. And yes this CSS example is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @MajiD did all of the hard work; I merely put it into a executable snippet. They deserve all of the credit. Appreciate the thanks though!

Comment: @james actually you taught me that. i didn't know about the snippet ;)

Comment: Well you got me on the right track both of you.. I've ultimately settled on using bootstrap accordion. I like it because it is pretty clean with little code to make it work.